# How to show progress in Date/time range in progress/seek bar android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-progressbar, android-seekbar

I need to show in progress bar time lapse. I have start date/time and end date/time, so between start/date/time and end/date/time progress should be showed.  Please help who had experience with this.

```
start========(current time)=======end
```

this is how it should looks like:

[image]

Comment: Try to calculate the milliseconds between the two dates and set that result as the progress of the bar. If you need to constantly update the progress you probably will need a timer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple small function:

```kotlin
fun progress(start: LocalDateTime,
             end: LocalDateTime,
             now: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()): Double = when {
    now <= start -> 0.0
    now >= end -> 1.0
    else -> start.until(now, ChronoUnit.SECONDS) /
            start.until(end, ChronoUnit.SECONDS).toDouble()
}
```

It has 3 different cases:

1. `now` is before or equal to `start` then the progress is `0`
2. `now` is after or equal to `end` then the progress is `1`
3. calculate `(now - start) / (end - start)` which gives a fraction in the range `0-1`

You can then take that fraction and multiply it by `100` to get the percentage:

```
val progress = progress(start, end)
val percentage = (progress * 100).roundToInt()
```